# Help with choosing a GUI library for RPI developpement

Tags: gui, python-3, software-development

I am currently coding an app for Raspberry Pi, the app is very GUI dependent.

During my research i saw online that tktinker is good for small/simple apps.

I got really excited for PyQt but found out that there is a licence involved which is like $550.

found also PySide which is super similar to PyQt but I've read that it is no longer being maintained by the community, and that the garbage collection well is garbage.

I am looking for something similar like PyQt (designer tool) and free or not as expensive as PyQt.

My Dev environment is windows since am not in the US the PI that I purchased is taking like 3 weeks to arrive so all my testing is on Windows, but the targeted device is RPI 3.

Comment: This is a linux or programming question. It is not a Raspberry Pi question unless this application requires access to the specific RasPi hardware. Can you give us more information about your app?

Comment: I would have put an answer, but I realize that you didn't give enough information. What is the requirements for this application? What language, what do you need it to do? I would have suggested JavaFX, included in Java 10. For me, it was easier than Python, even after 15 years of not programming. But I really never did much with Python, whereas I had almost 20 years of Python experience.

Comment: (sorry) I meant "20 years of JAVA experience" in my comment above.

Comment: Xojo might be an option for you. It can make Pi GUI (and console) apps and has a built-in layout designer. It doesn't run on the Pi so you do your development on Windows, Mac or Linux and transfer to the Pi. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "answer", per se, and we may be "skating on thin ice" in terms of whether your question (and my answer) are appropriate to this forum. That said, here's some things you could try:

It seems that you're interested in doing actual code development on a Windows PC with Raspberry Pi as the target device. This may not the best/most appropriate place for the question you've asked, but I don't think it's entirely "off topic" either. You may also want to try asking your question here: [Software Reccomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

And I must say this without acrimony: It would appear you've not put much effort into finding an answer for yourself. I say this because a couple of Google searches produced the following:

1. Read the [GitHub PyQt page](https://github.com/pyqt); in particular, review the [Unofficial PyQt5 via PyPI for Python 2.7 64-bit on Windows](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5) as this may be a no-cost version of PyQt. Note also [PyQt's License FAQ](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/license-faq) that **may** apply to your use of the no-cost version of PyQt.
2. Read the [Python GUI Programming Page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for still more ideas. And don't miss the [GUI Programming page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GUI%20Programming%20in%20Python) while you're in the neighborhood.

Hopefully, this will get you started. Come back here if you have RPi-related questions; however, any questions related to the software I've referenced above will probably be considered "off topic", and the moderators will close your question.

Comment: Take a look at "guizero"  for Python.

Comment: `guizero` looks interesting. BTW, if you want to make sure the OP (@RidaMarLey) sees your comment, either comment to his question, or use his handle in a comment to someone else (like this one).